# Jquery plugin for sticking a few table rows at the top of the page when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone recommend a jquery plugin that would allow you to stick a few rows at the top of the page

i.e. page loads, the content is in the right place, then once the content reaches the top of the page it gets fixed in place while the user scrolls...then if they scroll back up the content will go back to it's original place?

The content in question, would be a few TR elements.

I tried a few, but all the ones I tried had major issues, so I'm wondering if you could recommend a few more options for me? thanks

Comment: Do you still need a hand with this or have you managed to sort it out?

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's how I'd approach this.

First, we'd have a "target" div like this:

```
<div id="fixedHeader">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

that has the following CSS:

```
#fixedHeader
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  float, left, right, margin, etc: as you want them;
}

#fixedHeader:not(.active)
{
  display: none;
}
```

When the page first loads, we copy the table's `thead` into this div. Then when the user scrolls such that the top of the table is no longer visible, show this. When they scroll back up, hide it again. Hiding and showing I'll do by adding/removing the `active` class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // copy over the thead
    $('#fixedHeader > table > thead').html($('#theTable > thead').html());

    // show or hide the div as necessary.
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $('#theTable > thead').offset.top < $(window).scrollTop() )
        {
            $('#fixedHeader').addClass('active');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#fixedHeader').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Will run into problems if the user can scroll past the end of the table; if necessary, you can expand the if condition for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
$("body").on("scroll",function(){
  $("tr.stickToTop").each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().y<=0){
      $(this).css({
        position: "fixed",
        top:0
      });
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        position: "static",
        top:''
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Replace `$("tr.stickToTop")` with some jQuery selector that works for your `<tr />` elements.

Comment: This completely doesn't work with the latest jQuery.